# Вертикальное выравнивание по резиновой высоте.

Tags: css

привет.Подскажите способ вертикального выравнивания текста который работает с условиями:

1. -текст может быть многострочный.
2. -родитель не имеет фиксированной высоты.
3. -родитель имеет position:fixed;( читал что при этом нельзя   использовать display:table поэтому и пришел к вам просить совета) .
4. -давайте без js.

Comment: По моему, когнитивно-диссонативные условия

Comment: Обоснуй.У меня сообщение будет на весь экран вешаться с Position:fixed.Поэтому и высота 100%;.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте

```
<div style='position:fixed;'>
    <div style='display:table;height:100%;'>
        <div style='display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;'>
            content    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо.Решил.правда хотелось структуру
<div>Conment</div>